# failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Иногда при загрузке страницы появляется ошибка:

> `2016/10/11 22:58:24 [error] 14697#14697: *113320 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.site.eu/scripts/vacstatus/sbvacapi.php?steam=STEAM_0:1:22222): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  in /var/www/hooligun/data/www/site.ru/includes/RGAPI.php on line 33" while reading response header from upstream, client: 111.25.177.4, server: bans.rgmix.eu, request: "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/user.sock:", host: "bans.rgmix.eu", referrer: "http://site.ru/index.php?p=banlist&searchText=STEAM_0:1:222"`

Стоит nginx + php-fpm; Debian 7; ISPmanager 5.

Я так понимаю, нужно подкрутить какие то значения php-fpm?

Comment: А какой запрос у вас посылается в 33-ей строке файла `/var/www/hooligun/data/www/site.ru/includes/RGAPI.php`?

Comment: Проблема не в сервере. Просто не получается достучаться до удалённого сервера. Причин может быть много. Начиная с отсутствия юзерагента в хедерах запроса. Попробуйте переписать на cURL.